# Unable to get last character of string

Tags: c#, string

[image]

** Code: **

```
String test = "32132SSS654";
char Lastchar = test[test.Length - 1];

Assert.IsTrue((Lastchar).Equals("4"));
```

I am trying to get the last character from the string then doing assert but it returns me something extra like **52** with the last character **4** and that's why my assert getting fail.

Comment: Your comparison object should be `'4'`

Comment: "but it returns me something extra like 52 with the last character 4 and that's why my assert getting fail" - no, your assertion is failing because you're comparing a `char` with a `string`. I don't know how you're determining that it's "returning something like 52" but 52 is the Unicode code point for '4'. I'd expect the debugger to just show it as '4' though.

Comment: @NicoSchertler - Thank you. Make sense.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Yes now I understood that.

Comment: As an aside, rather than `Assert.IsTrue(Lastchar).Equals('4'))` it would be better to use `Assert.AreEqual('4', Lastchar);` - and then rename `Lastchar` to follow .NET naming conventions, e.g. `lastChar`.

Comment: @JonSkeet - That seems better solution. For sure I would like to follow it to assert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your `Equals` call you are comparing the `char` to a `string` (**"4"**):

```
char Lastchar = test[test.Length - 1];
Assert.IsTrue((Lastchar).Equals("4"));
```

This returns false because the types differ. If you compare to a `char` of **'4'** it will return true:

```
Assert.IsTrue((Lastchar).Equals('4'));
```

Comment: So you mean passing 4 within single quote should resolve issue?

Comment: Yes, that's true - chars are written with single quotes.

Comment: Okay. Make Sense.

Answer (score 3):

The last character is a `char` not a `string`:

```
Assert.IsTrue((Lastchar).Equals('4'));
```

(`char` literals use single quotes).

The `52` is the [ASCII value for the character "4"](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: You could also use `LastChar.ToString().Equals("4")`

Comment: @Raman - you could, if you wanted a *really* bad solution to a non-problem.

Answer (score 2):

The value of `Lastchar` is correct. `52` is the decimal representation / value for the character `4` (see [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)). It's just a debug specific display.

Answer (score 1):

52 is the ASCII value of the *character- 4* and you are comparing it wrongly to `"4"` which is a string type.

In C#, when you enclose a value in double quotes that is a string value. When you put them in single quotes that becomes a char value and within single quotes you can put any *single* char value.

Change your code to-

```
Assert.IsTrue((Lastchar).Equals('4'));
```

`Assert` not only compares the value but also compares the type of the object whether they are equal. So just in case if you compare something like-

```
Assert.IsTrue((4).Equals('4'));
```

would return false since it compares int value to a char value which would never be equal.